# SwiftUI compare time code crashed on iPhone 8 mini and iPhone 12 mini IOS 16

Tags: swift, swiftui

Please help it has drove me mad
I am using Xcode 14, both crashed device using IOS 16.
I have following code, it does not work on iPhone 8 Mini, iPhone 12 mini Real Device. it does work on the iPhone 12 Mini and iPhone 8 mini simulator and other real bigger sized iPhone Device.
I downloaded time string such as "19:00" if the current time less than this, button activated else disable button.

```
        let date = Date()
        let calender = Calendar.current
        
        let hour = calender.component(.hour, from: date)
        let minute = calender.component(.minute, from: date)
        
        let slotTime = splitTime(string: time.Time)
        
        
        let CurrentTimeString = "\(hour):\(minute)"
        let TimeSlotTimeString = slotTime
        let f = DateFormatter()
        f.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        
        if f.date(from: CurrentTimeString)! > f.date(from: slotTime)! {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

the crash message read found nil while unwrapping
[image]

/// I use my mouse over the error area, the Xcode does show the value.

[image]
///

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please edit your question to include your code **As code** not as screen-shots. If you also want to leave the screen-shots so we can see the crash info, fine, but we need the code.

Your code is using force-unwrapping.

I call the force-unwrap operator the "crash if nil" operator. That is what it does.

Don't use force-unwrapping. Rewrite your code to log a message if the date string can't be converted to a `Date`

You might have your different devices set up to different locales where the rules for date/time formatting are different.

Try displaying the current `Date()`to a string using your date formatter on each device and logging it to the console. My guess is that some of your devices are set to 12-hour time and some are set to 24 hour time.

When in 12 hour time the Date string "18:20" won't be valid.

Comment: I followed you advice, and has successfully fixed the problem. new knowledge learned. many thanks

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. You should post an answer to your question explaining in detail how you figured it out, and then what the solution was. Then you should accept that answer instead of mine. That way future readers can learn what you learned. (I just told you how to find the problem. You found the actual solution yourself.)